# wiris plugin with tinymce working on localhost, but not online

Tags: tinymce, rich-text-editor, html-editor

I have embedded wiris plugin with tinymce editor. On clicking the "tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor" button of wiris in the tool bar, the formula editor window is opening in local-host but not online, where I have hosted my site. Please tell the solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default WIRIS plugin uses the WIRIS editor services hosted at our servers in www.wiris.net. Please check that your server can connect to our servers. Additionaly, if you have a proxy/firewall in your server you need to include its configuration details in the plugin's configuration.ini file (http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/resources/configuration-table) uncommenting and setting the wirisproxy* variables.

Please check the WIRIS plugin test pages too: http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/resources/test

Comment: I went through the test pages, and got to know that "open_basedir restriction in effect". Now, what are the solutions, keeping in view that I don't have access to php.ini file.

Comment: Please confirm that you are using the latest WIRIS plugin version available and please provide the stack trace of the error.